# error out -- what exactly does this phrasal verb mean?

Tags: meaning, terminology

Source: [*You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes*](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch3.md)  by Kyle Simpson (2014)

Example:

> Now we have an infinite circular duplication problem because of the circular reference. Should we detect a circular reference and just break the circular traversal (leaving the deep element not fully duplicated)? Should we **error out** completely? Something in between?

What exactly would you say the phrasal verb *error out* means? Please, give a bunch of examples.

Comment: This has something to do with programming language, not English. **Error out** and **Error in** are two different types of [Error clusters](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=jqi9G2EyktYC&pg=PA488&lpg=PA488&dq=types+of+error+cluster&source=bl&ots=mxSL750dIs&sig=MqrJGN6kuC3aXzUtEBWltqUZEtE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR1sH_2dbJAhWBwI4KHdFyBYgQ6AEIUjAI#v=snippet&q=%22error%20in%22&f=false). Check [this link](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/lvhowto/using_error_clusters/), too.

Comment: @Usernew In this case, it's slang for "raise an error immediately", vs. attempting to recover. Error clusters are different.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Error out** is  programming jargon/slang that is synonymous with "bail out" -- exit the process *entirely* without attempting to recover *to some degree*.

The noun **error** is being used as a verb, a kind of shorthand for "raise an error".

Comment: Note that when you see a noun used as a verb it normally means to do what is normally done with the noun.  Thus to error out is to throw an error.

Comment: It's worth noting that in this context, "process" means the hypothetical `copy()` function or method, not "process" as in `firefox.exe`.